# Java- Load file from same package in NB platform application

Tags: java, file, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have the following piece of code,

```
public void vbsCalled() {
        try {
            String file = "src\\com\\first\\hello\\hello.vbs";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + file + " ");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RunVBS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I am using **netbeans** IDE,

**Scenario 1:**

1. I create a new java project (New Project -> Java -> Java Application)

The project Structure looks like below,

```
--Java Application1
  -Source Packages
    -com.first.hello //Package
       -ClassWhichHaveVbsCalledMethod.java
       -hello.vbs
```

with this am able to call the hello.vbs from same package and no error.

**Scenario 2:**

1. I create a netbeans platform application (New project - > Netbeans Modules ->NetBeans platform Application)

The project Structure looks like below,

[image]

`RunVBS.java` has the `vbsCalled()` Method and with the `hello.vbs` in same package as scenario 1,

Now, it looks for the file in

> "C:\application1\src\com\first\hello\hello.vbs"

and *shows no such file found error*.

How can i load the file in netbeans platform application as like scenario1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder in your project's root directory called release
2. Move hello.vbs to the release/ folder
3. Use the InstalledFileLocator class to get the runtime path of your file.

Here is what your vbsCalled() method would then look like.

```
public void vbsCalled() {
    try {
        File file = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate(
                      "hello.vbs", // filename relative to the release/ directory
                      "com.first.hello", // Your module's code name base __not package!__
                      false);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " ");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RunVBS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

See [DevFaqInstalledFileLocator](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqInstalledFileLocator) for more details